# Why does compiler throw an error when we declare an extra template argument and not used in definition?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a below code.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T,class U>
T myMax(T x, T y)
{
   return (x > y)? x: y;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << myMax(3, 7) << std::endl;  // Call myMax for int
  std::cout << myMax(3.0, 7.0) << std::endl; // call myMax for double
  std::cout << myMax('g', 'e') << std::endl;   // call myMax for char
  return 0;
}
```

On compiling the code, compiler reports an error as show below.

```
functionTemplates.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
functionTemplates.cpp:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘myMax(int, int)’
functionTemplates.cpp:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘myMax(double, double)’
functionTemplates.cpp:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘myMax(char, char)’
```

I know that if i remove class U, compilation will be successful.
But i want to know why does compiler bothers about an unused parameter?

Comment: Because the more possible problems the compiler can detect, the better.

Comment: Because the compiler cannot substitute `U` for any type because it hasn't been provided one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general case, a compiler can determine the template parameters from:

1. The arguments used to make the function call.
2. The explicitly used types to make the function call.

In your case, `U` cannot be determined from the arguments used to make the function call since `U` is not used by the arguments. The only other way the compiler can determine `U` is if it is used explicitly in the function call. E.g.

```
 std::cout << myMax<int, double>(3, 7) << std::endl;
```

---

**PS** It's not clear to me why you have `U` as a template parameter in the first place. It's not used at all. Won't it be easier to use:

```
template <class T>
T myMax(T x, T y)
{
   return (x > y)? x: y;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sahu sir, 
Thanks for answering my query. 
I was working on one API and i found that one of the template parameter was not useful and i removed it from function definition and i got the error which is described above. 
Later i found the root cause but i just wanted to know what might be the reason behind the error.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot determine the type of the unused template argument.  You need to specify it explicitly, or remove the unused template argument.